# Alfresco Script set group as assignee

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I'm using alfresco script and I'm starting a workflow using a script. 
I'm setting group assignee as reception:

```
wfparams["bpm:groupasignee"] = groups.getGroup('reception');
```

And starting workflow:

```
workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, wfparams);
```

Problem is showing in console:

> org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.WebScriptException: 04120017 Wrapped Exception (with status template): 04120067 Failed to execute script 'Javascript Console Script': 04120066 Failed to start workflow activiti$activitiParallelGroupReview:1:20.

Cause by:

> org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Couldn't serialize
>   value
>   '[org.alfresco.repo.security.authority.script.ScriptUser@36e9c1f8]' in
>   variable 'bpm_groupasignee'

How to assign a group to a workflow task? 
Greetings, Rafał

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign task to group, using script.Below is the code i have taken it from bpmn file, where `activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_GroupName"` used to assign  task to Group.In alfresco group are prefixed in backend as "GROUP_ ",so i think you have to assign task to "GROUP_reception".

```
<userTask id="PE" name="PE" activiti:candidateGroups="GROUP_PE" activiti:formKey="wf:adhocTask"></userTask>
```

Answer (score 0):

please try using this to assign a workflow to a group

```
wfparams["bpm:groupAssignee"] = people.getGroup("GROUP_YOUR_GROUP_NAME");
```